# In Jdeveloper 11G, how can i directly jump to an implementting method of an interface using a shortcut while analyzing source code

Tags: keyboard-shortcuts, jdeveloper

I have the below code in Jdeveloper 11g:

File Name: Test.java

```
package com.sample;

public class Test {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        SomeInterface interfaceRef = new SomeClass();

        interfaceRef.someMethod();
    }
}

class SomeClass implements SomeInterface {
    public void someMethod() {
        System.out.println("I am the implementation...");
    }
}

interface SomeInterface {
    public void someMethod();
}
```

When I press <kbd>CTRL</kbd> key and click on the `someMethod()` call ( i.e in the line `interfaceRef.someMethod()` in `main()` method). The cursor is taken to the interface's method declaration. I want to be able to directly go to the actual implementation method of SomeClass.

This is possible in Eclipse. When I press ctrl key and Hover over a method called on an interface, it shows me two options.

1. Open Declaration
2. Open Implementation.

If I click on Open Implementation, it goes to the implemented method in the someClass.

There is a way for this in jdeveloper using section 11.2.7 of the following [link](https://docs.oracle.com/middleware/1212/jdev/OJDUG/working_java_code.htm#OJDUG5635) but this involves multiple hops.

Can it be done in a single shortcut in Jdev?

Comment: YRP, You can also setup the [eclipse shortcuts](http://web-center-suite.blogspot.com/2011/08/jdeveloper-shortcuts.html) in Jdeveloper. This way you don't need to learn the shortcuts again.

Comment: Thanks Deepak, Thats a good idea, but did not solve my problem of directly jumping to the implementation class.